# Flask - handling unicode text with werkzeug?

Tags: unicode, http-headers, flask, werkzeug

So I am trying to have a browser download a file with a certain name, which is stored in a database. To prevent filename conflicts the file is saved on disk with a GUID, and when it comes time to actually download it, the filename from the database is supplied for the browser. The name is written in Japanese, and when I display it on the page it comes out fine, so it is stored OK in the database. When I try to actually have the browser download it under that name:

```
return send_from_directory(app.config['FILE_FOLDER'], name_on_disk, 
                           as_attachment=True, attachment_filename = filename)
```

Flask throws an error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 15-20: 
ordinal not in range(128)
```

The error seems to originate not from my code, but from part of Werkzeug:

```
/werkzeug/http.py", line 150, in quote_header_value
value = str(value)
```

Why is this happening? According to their docs, Flask is "100% Unicode"

I actually had this problem before I rewrote my code, and fixed it by modifying numerous things actually in Werkzeug, but I really do not want to have to do this for the deployed app because it is a pain and bad practice.

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 26 2013, 12:52:49) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

> > > filename = "[얼티메이트] [131225] TVアニメ「キルラキル」オリジナルサウンドトラック (FLAC).zip"
> > >
> > > print repr(filename)

```
'[\xec\x96\xbc\xed\x8b\xb0\xeb\xa9\x94\xec\x9d\xb4\xed\x8a\xb8] [131225] TV\xe3\x82\xa2\xe3\x83\x8b\xe3\x83\xa1\xe3\x80\x8c\xe3\x82\xad\xe3\x83\xab\xe3\x83\xa9\xe3\x82\xad\xe3\x83\xab\xe3\x80\x8d\xe3\x82\xaa\xe3\x83\xaa\xe3\x82\xb8\xe3\x83\x8a\xe3\x83\xab\xe3\x82\xb5\xe3\x82\xa6\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x83\x89\xe3\x83\x88\xe3\x83\xa9\xe3\x83\x83\xe3\x82\xaf (FLAC).zip'
>>>
```

Comment: could you add as an example a `repr(filename)`?

Comment: It's probably related to this Flask issue: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/1286 I.e. even though Flask might be "100% Unicode", unicode filename are not supported in the HTTP header and thus can't be supported by Flask itself.

Answer (score 3):

You should explictly pass unicode strings (type `unicode`) when dealing with non-ASCII data. Generally in Flask, bytestrings are assumed to have an `ascii` encoding.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. I originally had this to send the file as attachment:

```
return send_file(dl_fd,
                 mimetype='application/pdf',
                 as_attachment=True,
                 attachment_filename=filename)
```

where `dl_fd` is a file descriptor for my file.

The unicode filename didn't work because the HTTP header doesn't support it. Instead, based on information from [this Flask issue](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/1286) and these [test cases for RFC 2231](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/), I rewrote the above to encode the filename:

```
response = make_response(send_file(dl_fd,
                                   mimetype='application/pdf'
                                   ))
response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = \
    "attachment; " \
    "filename*=UTF-8''{quoted_filename}".format(
        quoted_filename=urllib.quote(filename.encode('utf8'))
    )

return response
```

Based on the [test cases](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/#attwithfn2231utf8comp), the above doesn't work with IE8 but works with the other browsers listed. (I personally tested Firefox, Safari and Chrome on Mac)

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like:

```
@route('/attachment/<int:attachment_id>/<filename>', methods=['GET'])
def attachment(attachment_id, filename):
    attachment_meta = AttachmentMeta(attachment_id, filename)
    if not attachment_meta:
        flask.abort(404)
    return flask.send_from_directory(
        directory=flask.current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
        filename=attachment_meta.filepath,
    )
```

This way `url_for('attachment',1,u'Москва 北京 תֵּל־אָבִיב.pdf')` would generate:

```
/attachment/1/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC%20%D7%AA%D6%B5%D6%BC%D7%9C%D6%BE%D7%90%D6%B8%D7%91%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%91.pdf
```

Browsers would display or save this file with correct unicode name. Don't use `as_attachment=True`, as this would not work.